# Prevent dialog from closing after restarting application

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dialog, restart

I am implementing a dialog and have a question. I set a timer for 10minutes. For 10 minutes, users cannot use the application. They can only see a dialog that tells them how long it is left. When they terminate and restart the application, they can only see the same dialog. How can I prevent a dialog from closing or show it again when a user restarts the application?

Thanks for the help.

> My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.OtpTimeLimitViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_information_button">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="message1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_tab_bar"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/content_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="message2"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_helper"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/timeLimit_timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@{viewModel.timeLimit}"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/content_text" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

> Fragment

```
class OtpTimeLimitFragment : DialogFragment() {

private lateinit var binding: DialogOtpLimitBinding
private lateinit var viewModel: OtpTimeLimitViewModel

private lateinit var mContext: MainActivity

private val args : AgreementViewDialogArgs by navArgs()

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    mContext = context as MainActivity
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    binding =  DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.dialog_otp_limit, container, false)
    dialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(OtpTimeLimitViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use shared preference for the same like you can store time when that timer should end and when user reopens the app then you check if that time is in the past and if that isn't the case then you should show the dialog when application reopens.

Comment: @KaranMehta I posted a function of shared preference that I have tried. Is this how I use it? Can you show me an example how to save the time with my code?

Comment: You don't need to store start time, instead you should store end time and then put condition on that, If that time is greater than current time then show dialog.

Comment: @KaranMehta I did it to prevent an error that the time stops when a user terminates the app. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can start timer again, right? If the end time is greater than current time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243570/discussion-between-lucy-and-karan-mehta).

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions about the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough example of what you need to do :

First of all, Store value like this :

```
var pref: SharedPreferences? = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("otpTrialLimit", MODE_PRIVATE)
        pref?.edit()?.putLong("endTime", endTime)
        pref?.edit()?.commit()
```

When user reopens the application then in

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(OtpTimeLimitViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel


    val sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("otpTrialLimit",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPreference.getLong("endTime", 0)

    if(System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime){
       //Show dialog here
    }
   }
```

Comment: @Lucy, Please let me know if this worked.

Comment: I am trying to apply this to my code. I have the following questions. 1) Where should I store value? 2) `OtpTimeLimitFragment` is a dialog fragment. Can I still show dialog there?

Comment: How to use shared preference in `startTimeLimit()` and call?

Comment: Store value in activity when login/submit button is pressed and then when again user reopens the app then in activity check if time has completed with above given code. and only show dialog if condition is not met.

Comment: @Lucy did it work?

Comment: No. It wasn't the answer. I could finally make it after remove & clear of `shared preference` was correctly used